# To concatenate with BSD Join

Tags: macos, terminal

I want to concatenate in BSD Join.

Data

```
Model Decreasing Constant Increasing
2025 75.5 82.5 89.5
2035 65.5 82.5 102
2050 49.5 82.5 112
```

and error configuration in ybar

```
Model Decreasing Constant Increasing
2025 2.5 2.5 2.5
2035 2.5 2.5 5
2050 7.5 7.5 7.5
```

which should be

```
2025 75.5 82.5 89.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
...
```

Unix variant `join A B` does work according to my friend.

### Outputs from Head

```
$ head model1_ave.dat
Year Decreasing Constant Increasing
2025 75.5 82.5 89.5
2035 65.5 82.5 102
2050 49.5 82.5 112
$ head model1_ave_err.dat 
Model Decreasing Constant Increasing
2025 2.5 2.5 2.5
2035 2.5 2.5 5
2050 7.5 7.5 7.5
```

**How can you concatenate the two files in OSX Join i.e BSD?**

Comment: Works for me with these files. Are you sure the line endings are unix-like and not DOS-style (DOS/Windows produce files with CR+LF at the end, unix tools prefer LF)?

Comment: `join -1 1 -2 1 <(grep -v Year model1_ave.dat) <(grep -v Model model1_ave_err.dat)` works :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join` works for me here:

```
pse@Mithos:~/t$ join -1 1 -2 1 t1 t2
Model Decreasing Constant Increasing Decreasing Constant Increasing
2025 75.5 82.5 89.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
2035 65.5 82.5 102 2.5 2.5 5
2050 49.5 82.5 112 7.5 7.5 7.5
```

In case there are non-matching header lines in each file you need to get rid of them first, otherwise the joining will fail.

```
pse@Mithos:~/t$ join -1 1 -2 1 <(grep -v Year t1) <(grep -v Model t2)
2025 75.5 82.5 89.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
2035 65.5 82.5 102 2.5 2.5 5
2050 49.5 82.5 112 7.5 7.5 7.5
```

Comment: Thank you for your addition! So `join` considers the headers in doing the joining.

Comment: `join` doesn't know about headers in the first place, it just joins (or tries to) lines of text

Comment: So the parameters `-1 1` and `-2 1` tells to `join` that use the first columns in the files as the pivot point if they are the same. When they were not the same, nothing come out.